# How to empty the value of textarea in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer

I would like to know if this is possible in puppeteer to empty the value of the textarea.
I have this textarea

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control  h-auto" placeholder="Add a description" data-object="" rows="3">Nisi facere laboriosam voluptas non sed soluta.</textarea>
```

I'm using this code but it doesn't work

```js
const description = await page.$('#description')
await description.click({clickCount: 3})
await description.press('Backspace')
await page.type('#description', data.description)
```

I want to empty description and replace it with new description faker. I did this also. It empty the value of textarea but I cant type new description anymore.

```js
await page.evaluate(function() {           
  document.querySelector('textarea#description').value = ''
})
```

Comment: It depends on the event handlers on the site, so this needs detail beyond the simple HTML element and a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As the same way you cleaned the textarea you could insert another string over there.

Did you also tried

```
await page.evaluate(function() {           
  document.querySelector('textarea#description').value = 'your-new-text'
})
```